# count and sum function not properly working

Tags: excel, count, sum

I am working in excel and for some reason my sum or count function is not working properly.  Or, perhaps I am not using the correct function or in the right way.

```
    A           B          C        D     E        F        G         H

    February    Max                       March    Max
    1           28          
    2
    3
    4
    5
    7
    11
    15
    17
    19
    22
    23
    25

    IF(SUM(A:A>0),28,"")
    IF(SUM(E:E>0),31,"")
```

I have the above columns, I want the Max columns to show a specific number only if there is data in their respective month column.  February has data, so it shows 28.  March does not have any data so it shows no max.  I need to look at the entire column or at least a large area (row 2 to row 2000).

The issue I am having is that if I do not have a value in the first row, but do have values in later rows, the sum or count function will to recognize that and will return zero.

```
    A           B        

    February    Max


    3
    4
    5
    7
    11
    15
    17
    19
    22
    23
    25

    IF(SUM(A:A>0),28,"")
```

I have tried both sum and count functions, neither are giving me the results I want.  I have also tried making `>= 1`.  I found from StackExchange that someone was having a similar problem and a solution was to change the cell format to a number.  That did not work either.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What if you just used [`COUNTA()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509)? `=IF(COUNTA(A:A)>0,28,"")`?

Comment: Perfect, that works.  Thank you!

Comment: The flaw you had in your formula is the misplaced `)`. You need to compare the sum against 0 after the closing bracket. So `IF(SUM(A:A)>0,28,"")` will return your value.

Comment: @JvdV, got it.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, you could use `COUNTA()` which checks if a cell is blank.

While it doesn't answer the technical reason `SUM`/`COUNT` isn't working, it should work for your intended purposes.

```
=IF(COUNTA(A:A)>0,28,"")
```

Comment: So just so I am clear, `COUNTA` will be looking at all the rows and will count how many cells are not blank?

Comment: Wait a second, I removed all the values in the column, but it still shows the value (28).

Comment: @Zman3 - Are the cells truly empty? "The Excel COUNTA function returns the count of cells that contain numbers, text, logical values, error values, and empty text (""). COUNTA does not count empty cells."

Comment: I highlighted the column and clicked clear all.  It still shows the value.

Comment: If you switch `A:A` with, say `AZ:AZ` does it still show `28`?

Comment: @BruceWyane, sorry, I had a mistake.  One of my perenthesis was in the wrong place.  I had `=IF(COUNTA(A:A>0),28,"")`.

Comment: So I have a header in the row with that equation.  Is there a way to exclude the header but keep `A:A`?